# Kafka Streams - Unit test for ProductionExceptionHandler implementation

Tags: unit-testing, exception, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-config

I am developing a  Kafka streams application that uses Spring Cloud streams for configuration.
In order to handle "RecordTooLargeException" I have implemented a custom ProductionExceptionHandler as below.

public  class CustomProductionExceptionHandler implements ProductionExceptionHandler {

```
 @Override
 public ProductionExceptionHandlerResponse handle(ProducerRecord<byte[], byte[]> record,
                                                 Exception exception) {
    if (exception instanceof RecordTooLargeException) {
      
        return ProductionExceptionHandlerResponse.CONTINUE;
    }
    return ProductionExceptionHandlerResponse.FAIL;
 }

 @Override
 public void configure(Map<String, ?> configs) {
 }

}
```

I have added the following property in my application.yml

```
spring.kafka:
    streams:
     properties:
       default.production.exception.handler: "com.fd.acquisition.product.availability.product.exception.StreamsRecordProducerErrorHandler"
```

The code works fine as the default failing behavior is overridden and the processing is continued.

I am trying to write unit test cases to simulate this behaviour.
I am making use of TopologyTestDriver and it has the following configuration.

```
    Properties streamsConfiguration = new Properties();
    streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "TopologyTestDriver");
    streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "dummy:1234");
    streamsConfiguration.put(ProducerConfig.MAX_REQUEST_SIZE_CONFIG, "200");
    streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
    streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.CACHE_MAX_BYTES_BUFFERING_CONFIG, (10 * 1024 ));
    streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.SEND_BUFFER_CONFIG, (10 ));
    streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.RECEIVE_BUFFER_CONFIG, (10 ));

    final String tempDrectory = Files.createTempDirectory("kafka-streams").toAbsolutePath().toString();
    streamsConfiguration.setProperty(StreamsConfig.STATE_DIR_CONFIG, tempDrectory);
    streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_PRODUCTION_EXCEPTION_HANDLER_CLASS_CONFIG,
            CustomProductionExceptionHandler.class);
```

Ideally, the size of the record should throw RecordTooLargeException when I push a large record.
But the MockProducer class is used instead of KafkaProducer and hence the ensureValidRecordSize() method is never called.

Is there any way to override this behaviour or any other way to simulate the RecordTooLargeException ?

Comment: Instead of using `TopologyTestDriver` you could use `EmbeddedBroker` (not a public class though) to write an integration test. -- But frankly, the handler seem fairly simple, and thus, I am not sure how critical it is to test it? If course, it doesn't hurt to have unit test what that verifies that the handler return `CONTINUE` when the `RecordTooLargeException` is passed into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is basically a feature missing from `MockProducer`. So the first option would be to contribute a PR back to Kafka that adds the missing check to `MockProducer`. It looks that it should be fairly easy to add it. If you are not a developer, alternatively you can create an issue and hope somebody from the community will pick it up.

Either way, you will have to wait for the next Kafka release to get the feature. You have to decide whether you can live without the unit test until then. There could be ways to hack this (use reflection to make `TopologyTestDriver.producer` visible / non-final and replace it by an "improved" version of `MockProducer`), but it's probably going to be harder than to just contribute to Kafka.